# WordPress Post Thumbnail Problem

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two types of posts in the theme I am creating Trending and Normal. Post thumbnail image size is: 300x169 and I show it as that size when a trending post is displayed. But when this post is not trending I want the thumbnail size to be: 145x80. I tried `the_post_thumbnail( array(145,80) );` but it doesn't work. Instead this crops the image in squarish dimensions. I don't want it to crop but decrease in size via HTML.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks! Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding a new image size and then when you call the_post_thumbnail you pass it the name of the new image size you have set. Set the hardcrop flag to false if you don't wan't the image resizing via hard crop.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: I just realized that the thumbnails in the primary WordPress loop are defaulting to 155*155. Any idea why. I made a mistake thinking it was cropped wrongly. It's just distorted wrongly. My functions file has nothing to do with that.

if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
 add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
 set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 169, true );
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
 add_image_size( 'normal-thumb', 145, 80, false );
}

Comment: I used what you suggested and added a image size. Worked but the image still defaults to 155*155 even though the img height and width in the code are what I want...

Comment: can you post a link? You don't have a CSS style attached to the images do you? Also have you tried re-uploading the original image since you made the changes? It won't downsize images after they have been uploaded even if you set a new image size.

Comment: I had a style attached right at the bottom of my style sheet. It works now. Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size from CSS by doing this:

`<div style="width:145px;height:80px;"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>`